# phantomjs child process execution under cygwin

Tags: cygwin, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to call shell script from casperjs script under cygwin environment. Code below prints output if I use system commands like "ls, pwd, find...". But when I specify custom.sh script inside execFile function it prints nothing. And it looks like execFile doesn't trigger shell script.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({   
    verbose: true, 
    logLevel: 'debug',
});
var cp = require('child_process');

casper.start();

casper.then(function(){  
    cp.execFile('custom.sh', 'arg', {}, function (err, stdout, stderr) {    
            console.log("execFileSTDOUT:", JSON.stringify(stdout));
            console.log("execFileSTDERR:", JSON.stringify(stderr));
    });

    casper.waitFor(function check () {
        return false;
    }, function then() {
        console.log('Success').exit();
    }, function timeout() {
        this.echo("Timeout!!!").exit();
    }, 3000)
});

casper.run();
```

**custom.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo >&2 some message
echo "code";
echo "xxx" > trigger.log
```

custom.sh prints output if I run it directly from command line:

```
$ custom.sh
some message
code
```

But there is nothing in casper log:

```
$ casperjs test.js
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 1 step
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
execFileSTDOUT: ""
execFileSTDERR: ""
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 1/1: done in 38ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 2/2: done in 50ms.
```

I tried to put custom.sh inside /usr/bin and specify absolute path but without success.

**EDIT:**

One point to mention 
cp.execFile('/usr/bin/ls', '/' - returns nothing
cp.execFile('ls', '/' - outputs files listing

Comment: Have you tried to use `cp.execFile('sh custom.sh',...`?

Comment: i tried cp.execFile('/usr/bin/sh', 'custom.sh',...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is related to cygwin path parameters.

Finally function call below works as expected:

```
cp.execFile('sh', 'custom.sh' ...
```